# Resize a Notification Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications, resize

can I programmatically resize notification to size specify?
My code js:

```
 var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('http://mypage');
 notification.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the height will adjust to fit the content (not sure of an upper limit) but the width is fixed.